# .NET String Encoding Issue

Tags: arrays, .net, string

I am converting some data from a byte array to a string using the following code:

```
var res = new List<byte>();
Encoding.UTF8.GetString(res.ToArray());
```

Upon inspecting in the debugger, it has a number of non-printable characters after it:

"USD\0�(j\f�\u007f"

When i click on the magnifying glass on the property in the debugger, Visual Studio correctly identifies the string as just USD, but when this string is passed to other methods obviously the whole lot is passed.

I need the string in the format that Visual Studio identifies it as, i.e USD, so i am guessing there is a function to sanitise it?

Comment: How are you getting from a byte array to a string?

Comment: Updated question to include conversion code

Comment: What encoding do you expect in that byte array? What you show looks like kind of a “buffer overflow” scenario — a null-terminated string having three ASCII characters (“USD”) + some extra binary garbage. So: how do you produce or where do you get that byte array from?

Comment: well this is where it gets fun. The actual binary data is coming from a number of 3rd party services, all running the same API. I am lead to believe that it is UTF8, and for the most part it does return what i am expecting. The buffer overflow is an interesting idea...

Comment: It is a limitation of the VS debugger, it uses an operating system function to display the string content and that function treats \0 as a string terminator.  Encoding.GetString() does not, it translates all of the bytes in the array.  If you can't fix the service then you'll have to trim the string yourself, use String.IndexOf() to find the 0 back.  Actual encoding can't be guessed from "USD", other than that it an 8-bit encoding.

Comment: The debugger is doing exactly the right thing. .NET strings are not null-terminated. The debugger is correctly displaying (as best it can) all of the characters in the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will do the input sanitizing you need.

```
// Sample input with bytes beyond the null terminator.
byte[] binary = { (byte) '0', (byte) '1', (byte) '2', 0, (byte) '8', (byte) '9' };
int length;

// Find the null terminator or total length of input.
for (length = 0; length < binary.Length && binary[length] > 0; ++length);

string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(binary, 0, length);
```